# Htaccess for Silex

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, mod-rewrite, silex

I'm trying **Silex** for first time but I can't get a simple call with a friendly URL to work properly, but if I use a non friendly URL it does it's job. I'm experimenting in localhost and the domain is

> *localhost/site*

and the structure looks like this:

```
site
|- ...
|- .htaccess
|- /php/
   |- rest.php
```

The .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ php/rest.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I try calling

> *localhost/site/php/rest.php/anything*

It works properly and returns the expected value, but if I try this

> *localhost/site/rest/anything*

It just keep saying

> **No route found for "GET /site/rest/anything"**

When the route for it to work must be `/anything`

I have tried:

- Moving .htaccess to `/php/`.
- Changing the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^ rest.php [QSA,L]`.
- Changing the RewriteBase to `RewriteBase /site/php/` and `/site/`.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the RewriteBase should be `/site/`...

Comment: I'm specifically saying that your `RewriteBase` should be `/site/` (and not `/site/php/`) when the `.htaccess` file is in the `site` directory.

Comment: @MikeRockett I tried that too with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually think this is possible, because Silex doesn't look for the `/$1`, and can only see what's in your address bar. (Unless the `rest.php` resides in the directory being requested.)

Your best bet would probably to reconsider your directory structure. If the web root for Silex is the `php` folder, then the request should be made to `localhost/site/php/anything`, with the `.htaccess` file being in that directory.

Alternatively, just rename the `php` folder to `rest`, and make sure you use the following rules (`.htaccess` file saved in the `rest` directory):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /site/rest/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ rest.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Lastly, you could just define you routes in Silex as `site/rest/{anything}` without changing your current setup. That is cumbersome, though, which leaves the previous option as the best option.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem, I don't care to rename the `php` folder to `rest`, and now it works perfectly. Thanks!